# as3 simple slider

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

My goal is tio buid a simpleslider in as3
This nearly works.. but the only trouble is: 
when you click drag the slider and you go out from the track, the slider is still being dragged.

I guess there is a simple trick to prevent that nasty effect

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle; public class SliderH extends MovieClip {
    public function SliderH() {
        trace("creation");
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousedown);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseup);
        this.buttonMode = true;
    }
    private function mousedown(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("begin");
        var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(-this.parent.width/2,0,this.parent.width,0);
        startDrag(false , rect);

    }
    private function mouseup(e:MouseEvent):void {
        stopDrag();
        trace(this.x);
    }       
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

While I'm all for doing stuff and learning along the way, Keith Peters has a great simple library that's pretty easy to setup. (if you're trying to create simple controls)

http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2979

but besides that, you should add a ROLL_OUT event `flash.events.MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT`

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseup);
```

Comment: if you do that and moves quiclky the slider, it stops dreagging !

Comment: add a bigger invisible area around the slider that shows up on ondown

Answer (score 0):

you want to prevent the slider from moving if you mouse is too far away,

i would do it by adding a event listener for when the mouse moves, if the distance from the slider becomes too much stop the drag early, I'm not sure exactly how your slider works but this may help.

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle; public class SliderH extends MovieClip {
    public function SliderH() {
        trace("creation");
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousedown);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseup);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mousemove);
        this.buttonMode = true;
    }
    private function mousedown(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("begin");
        var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(-this.parent.width/2,0,this.parent.width,0);
        startDrag(false , rect);

    }
    private function mouseup(e:MouseEvent):void {
        stopDrag();
        trace(this.x);
    }
    private function mousemove(e:MouseEvent):void{
        if (Math.abs(this.x)>this.parent.width/2){
            stopDrag();
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: This does not help. Still the SAME trouble.